# MS SQL User login and Privileges

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create a user that can only read and insert the data but not allowed to update or delete. When I use

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON employee TO Reader
```

I can do that but, I have some stored procedures too and when I gave the permissions to the user to execute stored procedures, the user can now execute delete/update stored procedures too.

How can I restrict the user's permissions?

Comment: first try to found solution on google after put your question here.

Answer (score 2):

yes. that would work. but if you need to grant execute rights to numerous SPs, try the code below:

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT EXEC ON ', o.name, ' TO <YourDBRoleHere>')
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
1.Create a role
2.Grant privileges to execute stored procedures one by one

```
Create Role MyReader
Grant EXEC ON GetAllDesignations TO MyReader;
```